Cannot mock the method in dependency module correctly in Python
Here is my project structure
|-- project
    |-- util.py
    |-- main.py
    |-- tests
        |-- test_main.py

In the main.py file I reference the function in util.py
from util import rename

def use_rename():
    after_rename = rename("name")
    return after_rename

And this is how I implement the rename function in util.py
def rename(name: str) -> str:
    return name

Finally I test it in the test_main.py file
import sys
import os
from unittest.mock import patch

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), ".."))

from main import use_rename

@patch("util.rename")
def test_use_rename(mock_rename):
    mock_rename.return_value = "name2"
    assert use_rename() == "name"

As you can see I try to mock the return result of the rename function and assume the test should fail, but it always succeeds. Is there anything wrong with my code?

There is only one error in your code: you mock the function rename in the module util where it is defined, but you have to mock the object util imported in the main.py module by the instruction:
from util import rename

So you need to do only a change in test_main.py:
import sys
import os
from unittest.mock import patch

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), ".."))

from main import use_rename

#@patch("util.rename")    # <--- comment this decorator
@patch("main.rename")     # <--- add this decorator
def test_use_rename(mock_rename):
    mock_rename.return_value = "name2"
    assert use_rename() == "name"

With this change the output of the execution is:
...
    assert use_rename() == "name"
AssertionError


@hh54188 A feedback would be appreciated.
